# why ajax loader image always shown using jquery and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, updatepanel

with asp.net code below my ajax_loader image doesn't work well and always shown  ..

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblname">
                        Name</asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbname"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblemail" runat="server">
                        Email</asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbemail" /><br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblsugg">
                        Suggestion</asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Rows="3" Columns="20" ID="txbsugg" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnsubmit" OnClick="btnsubmit_onclick" Text="submit" />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblresultmsg"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <div id="loading">
                <p>
                    <img src="Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                    Please Wait</p>
            </div>
```

and jquery code

```
    $("#loading").ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

any suggestions !?

Comment: Why not use the UpdateProgress control?  It does all of that automatically. See: [Introduction to the UpdateProgress Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a generic way to handle this by adding the following code to a common js include.  Here's a quick and dirty example:

Note: Be sure you initialize it by calling `SetupGlobalAjaxHandlers` on your page load.

```
function SetupGlobalAjaxHandlers()
{
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest); 
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
}

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) 
{ 
    if(typeof(OnPageInitRequest) != "undefined")
        OnPageInitRequest();
} 

function EndRequest(sender, args) 
{ 
    if(typeof(OnPageEndRequest) != "undefined")
        OnPageEndRequest();
}
```

Then, in any page that includes the js file, you could optionally implement the `OnPageInitiRequest()` and `OnPageEndRequest()` methods.  There, you could show/hide your loading indicator.

I do recommend, though, that you use an [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx) control as you get the show/hide logic for free.

This technique opens up some possibilities for you, say, if you wanted to disable controls while a partial postback is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

`ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` works only for ajax request sent by jQuery, if you use other libraries or `UpdatePanel`, it won't help you.
**jQuery only.**

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent **{With jQuery-gdoron}**, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in progress, jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStart() method are executed at this time.

Example of jQuery ajax request that will fire the `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'foo',
        ...
        ...
    });
```